# Crepi il lupo in English?

Tags: british-english

What is the English version of the Italian:

*"In bocca al lupo / Crepi"Crepi il lupo"?*

Is this correct?:

*"Good luck! / Cracks the wolf"*

Comment: 'Good luck' is the correct translation, but just as 'buona fortuna' carries with it some superstitious disease in Italian, the thespian idiom 'break a leg' is a very widely-understood alternative. Unlike Italian with 'crepi', there isn't a stock response to 'good luck'/'break a leg' — you just say 'thanks'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a question on translation and non-English languages is off-topic here and the question suits better on [Italian Language Stack Exchange](http://italian.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: **Translation into English is on-topic on ELU.** But it's important to give some context, which is missing here. "Cracks the wolf" certainly isn't idiomatic: under what circumstances is it used?

Comment: @AndrewLeach there is some superstition in Italian against saying *good luck* (*buona fortuna*) directly. Instead, one says *in bocca al lupo*, which literally translates as 'in the mouth of the wolf' (I have no idea of where this originates from). When receiving such a wish, the standard, idiomatic response is to reply with *crepi*, which literally translates as 'cracks', but the full-length response is *crepi il lupo*, which I was told conveys some hope of being able to kill the wolf. I understood the question as asking if there is some equivalent reply to a wish of good luck in English.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the origin of *in bocca al lupo* is thespian, in a parallel of *break a leg*, the English language's own superstitious aversion to the direct wishing of *good luck*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_bocca_al_lupo

Comment: @AndrewLeach I don't understand your comment. If there is context in a question asking about its equivalent, I don't think it is a request for translation. It is rather a request for an expression, idiom or phrase which has same meaning. How can users on ELU answer those questions unless they speak other languages?

Comment: http://italianowithjodina.com/2009/11/italian-idiom-of-the-week-2/